# SafeValue must use [property] getting appended to url in iframe src (Angular 14)

Tags: angular, iframe, angular14, property-binding

I am binding a link in iframe src as below

```
public resultLink: SafeResourceUrl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

this.resultLink = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(searchResult.pageUrl);

<iframe title="Finder Results" [src]="resultLink"></iframe>
```

But I am getting following output

```
<iframe title="Finder Results"  src="SafeValue must use [property]=binding: www.testurl.com (See https://g.co/ng/security#xss)"></iframe>
```

How can we fix this?

Comment: Is this the actual site you're trying to access `mytesturl.com`? are these `“”` present in your code?. Do you have protocol before `mytesturl.com`?

Comment: I see you corrected your question. Error does not reproduce though, if the value of `earchResult.pageUrl` is for instance `http://www.testurl.com`

Answer (score 0):

It could related to `safeUrl`:

```
<iframe title="Finder Results" [src]="resultLink | safeUrl"></iframe>
```